# iOS - Two sqlite3 databases in Documents appFolder - How to select which I want to use

Tags: ios, database, sqlite, restore

I have two or more databases in my app's Resources folder, i have copied them in Documents folder and my question is:

How to select in my app, which database i want to open?? Can I replace just the name of db in code?

In my app I have an UITextfield that user enters the name of the database he wants to open.

Comment: Impossible to figure out. I will say "yea, just change a name in code", but none of us know if this databases has the same columns and so on, so on..

Comment: Sorry I did'nt mention that. The database structure is the same (same tables), the only thing that changes are the values of rows. The databases is just backups that i made from the original db file.

Comment: In this case simple change name should work perfectly.

Comment: Just pass the proper path to the `sqlite3_open_v2` call.

Comment: Why do you make the user type in the name? Why don't you provide a list of databases the user can select from?

Comment: rmaddy I will do this in that way!! Thanks! But I have a problem. How i will pass the name of the restore db file into the connect method??

Answer (score 0):

Are you using CoreData? Your question lacks specifics, and code...

If you are using CoreData, then the database and managed object model are paired up when you create the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`

The managed object model you created is invoked while creating the NSManagedObjectModel like this:

```
NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"NameOfModelGoesHere" withExtension:@"momd"];
_managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
```

And later you pair up that NSManagedObjectModel with a specific database while creating the NSPersistentStoreCoordinator like this:

```
NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"NameOfDataBaseGoesHere.sqlite"];

NSError *error = nil;
_persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {
}

return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
```

It's entirely possible to have multiple persistentStoreCoordinators set up, each referencing separate databases and models, but invoking them and keeping track of them is entirely up to you. Naming conventions help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i am using sqlite3.

Comment: Another great reason to add detail to your questions to improve not only your chance of a response, but the relevance of the responses as well...